# Sanitizing a form's database input while retaining basic HTML markup

Tags: php

Is there a way to sanitize database input (say, for a comment form), which also allows for the end user to use basic HTML styling markup? As in, if a user wraps their text in `<i>`/`<em>` or `<strong>`/`<bold>`, the text gets styled, all while preventing users from entering malicious PHP and SQL commands?

Comment: First you have to decide what tags you will allow.  Then you can strip all others (including `<?php`).  To prevent SQL injection, use prepared statements (the details depend on what DB abstraction layer do you use).

Answer (score 4):

There have been a few great discussions of this at Stack Overflow.  [This one covers methods and processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions), but [don't try to create a catch-all function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions) as a replacement for understanding your data flows.

For your particular problem, it looks like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) might be a good fit.  That way, you could whitelist very specific HTML functionality (e.g., strong, ol, em) to prevent XSS.  In addition, you can parameterize your queries (check out [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com/php.html) for PHP specifics) to prevent SQL injection.

I wouldn't think of these two as one process, though, because they're really useful at different points in your application lifecycle:  parameterizing your SQL queries is important when you're about to make a SQL call, but XSS protection is important when displaying the saved data in a Javascript-equipped browser (as opposed to saving text to the database).